# How to copy an SVG element's content to another SVG element and keep synchronization

Tags: svg

Having two SVG elements ( SVG1 and SVG2 ) where SVG1 is a large area with various elements, that get added, removed and repositioned from time to time.  SVG2 on the other hand needs to be used to act as an **iconized reppresentation (small)** version of SVG1, being quite smaller, but whatever SVG1 shows, SVG2 shows in a very small scale.

```
<SVG id="SVG1" width=1000 height=1000>
    <g transform="scale(1)">
    .... elements here....
    </g>
</SVG>

<SVG id="SVG2" width=100 height=100>
    <g transform="scale(0.1)">
    .... elements here....
    </g>
</SVG>
```

I believe the approach is to programmatically synchronize the element changes that end up on SVG1 so they also end up on SVG2, with unique IDs of course.

... but I wonder if there is a simpler way that ensures that, something like a mirroring feature or something that, or alternatively scan down the DOM tree of SVG1 and replicate it into SVG2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the second SVG just a `<use>` element that points to the first. You can scale the `<use>` using a transform. It will always reflect whatever you do to the first SVG automatically.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <use transform="scale(0.1)" xlink:href="#SVG1"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Outstanding feature. I knew there could be something simple like that.